# Loading an ECC private key in .NET

Tags: c#, cryptography, x509certificate2

I have an ECC private and a certificate file which includes the public key. I can get them in either PEM or DER formats.

I can read the certificate into an `X509Certificate` with this code:

```
var certbytes = File.ReadAllBytes("certificate.pem");
var cert = new X509Certificate2(certbytes);
```

But I'm unable to load the private key. I've tried this code:

```
var keyContent = File.ReadAllBytes("certificate_private_key.pem");
var key = CngKey.Import(keyContent, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPrivateBlob);
```

It throws `Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper.WindowsCryptographicException: 'An error occurred during encode or decode operation'`.

I've also tried other values of the `CngKeyBlobFormat` parameter. The Import method fails with those as well.

openssl can read the file, and it outputs the following information about it:

```
openssl ec -in certificate_private_key.pem -text
read EC key
Private-Key: (256 bit)
priv:
    44:<cut>:68
pub:
    04:<cut>:13
ASN1 OID: prime256v1
NIST CURVE: P-256
writing EC key
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHcC <cut here>
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Is there built-in API in .NET or .NET Core which can do this? Or are there 3rd party libraries that can do it, and how?

Comment: Thank you for the tip. `openssl pkcs8` can't understand the file, only `openssl ec`. I already have the file in both DER and PEM formats, neither work. Depending on the `CngKeyBlobFormat` parameter, the exception is either `An error occurred during encode or decode operation` or `The parameter is incorrect`. I've also tried converting the DER file to an explicit EC file with `openssl ec -in certificate_private_key.der -inform DER -param_enc explicit -out explicit.der -outform der`, and using `CngKeyBlobFormat.EccFullPrivateBlob` as the format, but it still fails when importing.

Comment: Ah, it is in X9.62 format in that case. Should have seen that from the `-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----` header really. X9.62 private key is what is *within* a PKCS#8 file.

Comment: Try `openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in oldfile.pem -out newfile.pem` - probably works as well with `-outform DER` I guess.

Comment: Any luck with that? First converting to binary PKCS#8 format and then using `Pkcs8PrivateBlob` should really work.

Comment: Yes, that works. (Sorry for the late reply - other work and sleep got in the way). Now the DER file can be read using `var privatekey = File.ReadAllBytes("newfile.der"); var privkey = CngKey.Import(privatekey, CngKeyBlobFormat.Pkcs8PrivateBlob); var privkeyecdsa = new ECDsaCng(privkey);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

.NET Core 3.0 (currently in preview) has `ECDsa.ImportECPrivateKey`, `AsymmetricAlgorithm.ImportPkcs8PrivateKey`, and `AsymmetricAlgorithm.ImportEncryptedPkcs8PrivateKey`, (and RSA has RSAPublicKey and RSAPrivateKey) and for the current file (`BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY`) you'd want the first one.

- The good news of those methods is: they exist.
- The bad news is: They're part of the next version, not the current one.
- Good: The next version should be the current version soonishly.
- Bad: They only understand BER/DER data, not PEM.

The last point means that you currently would have to find the base64 content between the `-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----\n` and `\n-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----` and de-base64-it, then pass that into the methods.

---

The only private key formats that I know that are supported by CNG import are PKCS8, encrypted PKCS8, and CNG private formats.  To use CngKey.Import you'd first need to convert the keyfile to PKCS#8 then specify that the format is `Pkcs8PrivateBlob`, as suggested in the comments.

Comment: Are there any PEM decoding utilities in .NET or would you have to use e.g. Bouncy?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes There isn't one currently.  Either hand-rolled or something like BouncyCastle's PEMParser are the way to go for now.  Maybe next version I can get one in that's RFC 7468-compliant (e.g. ignore the headers section from RFC 1421).

Comment: Thank you, @bartonjs, this works. Using the DER encoded version of the original file that was described in the question, I can do `var ecdsa = ECDsa.Create(); ecdsa.ImportECPrivateKey(privatekey, out _);             ecdsa.VerifyHash(dataToVerify, signature);` I'm pretty sure that .NET Core 3.0 will be out before this needs to go in production, so I think I'll go down this road.