# .NET Core 3 unable to load ECC private key

Tags: c#, cryptography, elliptic-curve, .net-core-3.0

Thanks to [Loading an ECC private key in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56144550/loading-an-ecc-private-key-in-net), I'm able to load ECC private keys into .NET Core 3 and performing signature tasks with them.

I have, however run into *one* key that cannot be loaded by `ECDSA.ImportPrivateKey`. What's weird is that looking at it with `openssl` changes the key bytes to something that .NET Core 3 **can** understand.

Code to import the failing private key (this is the actual key that fails):

```cs
ecdsa = ECDsa.Create();
var pem = "MHYCAQEEH5t2Xlmsw5uqw3W9+/3nosFi6i3V901uW6ZzUpvVM0qgCgYIKoZIzj0DAQehRANCAASck2UuMxfyDYBdJC0mHNeToqMBhJuMZYSgkUNbK/xzD7e3cwr5okPx0pZdSMfDmyi1dBujtIIxFK9va1bdVAR9";
var derArray = Convert.FromBase64String(pem);
ecdsa.ImportECPrivateKey(derArray, out _);
```

The `ImportECPrivateKey` call fails with `System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException : ASN1 corrupted data` inside `` System.Security.Cryptography.EccKeyFormatHelper.FromECPrivateKey(ReadOnlyMemory`1 keyData, AlgorithmIdentifierAsn& algId, ECParameters& ret) ``

The original PEM file looks like this:

```
$ cat private_key_cert_265.pem
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHYCAQEEH5t2Xlmsw5uqw3W9+/3nosFi6i3V901uW6ZzUpvVM0qgCgYIKoZIzj0D
AQehRANCAASck2UuMxfyDYBdJC0mHNeToqMBhJuMZYSgkUNbK/xzD7e3cwr5okPx
0pZdSMfDmyi1dBujtIIxFK9va1bdVAR9
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

openssl converts the private key to something else:

```
$ openssl ec -in private_key_cert_265.pem
read EC key
writing EC key
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHcCAQEEIACbdl5ZrMObqsN1vfv956LBYuot1fdNblumc1Kb1TNKoAoGCCqGSM49
AwEHoUQDQgAEnJNlLjMX8g2AXSQtJhzXk6KjAYSbjGWEoJFDWyv8cw+3t3MK+aJD
8dKWXUjHw5sotXQbo7SCMRSvb2tW3VQEfQ==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Using this form of the PEM file, .NET Core 3 **can** import the private key.

My question is: What is going on; Why is openssl changing the private key to another format (how can I tell which format is which?), and why can .NET Core 3 understand one format and not the other?

Comment: Not all private keys are valid for every encryption algorithms.  The exception is indicating the keys is not valid for the algorithm you are using.  The private key posted looks like it is a 64 base string and may need to be decoded into bytes before using.

Comment: I posted the keys as their base64 representations for easier reading. The line `var derArray = Convert.FromBase64String(pem);` converts the key to the DER byte array.

Comment: Keys have required lengths and CRC.  You private key is not meeting requirements.  So the key is probably for a different algorithm, or you are implementing the wrong algorithm.  There a lots of options   Every time you use a private key an different temporary key will be used for each message so it makes it very hard to crack the key.  So I think the SSL key is the temporary key (or public key) that is generated from the Private key.  The temporary key is usually created from the private key and the Time message was generated along with a

Comment: @jdweng Your comments are completely missing the mark, this is an encoding error by the sending party.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initial key is incorrectly formatted. The private value S has not been left-padded correctly. The value S is transmitted as an unsigned, big endian integer within an ASN.1 octet string. This octet string (byte array) must have the same size as the key size in bytes, by definition. That means that it must be 32 bytes for the 256 bit curve that you are using (secp256r1, known under different names).

So your code and the .NET code is correct. OpenSSL seems more liberal what it accepts, but it writes out the value S as it should be.

---

Below is the initial private key value, taken from [here](https://lapo.it/asn1js/#MHYCAQEEH5t2Xlmsw5uqw3W9-_3nosFi6i3V901uW6ZzUpvVM0qgCgYIKoZIzj0DAQehRANCAASck2UuMxfyDYBdJC0mHNeToqMBhJuMZYSgkUNbK_xzD7e3cwr5okPx0pZdSMfDmyi1dBujtIIxFK9va1bdVAR9):

```
SEQUENCE (4 elem)
  INTEGER 1
  OCTET STRING (31 byte) 9B765E59ACC39BAAC375BDFBFDE7A2C162EA2DD5F74D6E5BA673529BD5334A
  [0] (1 elem)
    OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.2.840.10045.3.1.7 prime256v1 (ANSI X9.62 named elliptic curve)
  [1] (1 elem)
    BIT STRING (520 bit) 0000010010011100100100110110010100101110001100110001011111110010000011…
```

and here is the OpenSSL-corrected one:

```
SEQUENCE (4 elem)
  INTEGER 1
  OCTET STRING (32 byte) 009B765E59ACC39BAAC375BDFBFDE7A2C162EA2DD5F74D6E5BA673529BD5334A
  [0] (1 elem)
    OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.2.840.10045.3.1.7 prime256v1 (ANSI X9.62 named elliptic curve)
  [1] (1 elem)
    BIT STRING (520 bit) 0000010010011100100100110110010100101110001100110001011111110010000011…
```

and note the size of the OCTET STRING value and preceding zero.

---

This private key now has been compromised, of course. Note that there is a smaller chance of two `00` bytes missing, or three (etc.).

Comment: Thank you, that is it. RFC5915 shows how the string length is calculated and there is some discussion about an OpenSSL bug about this on the [openssl-dev mailing list](https://mta.openssl.org/pipermail/openssl-dev/2015-January/000297.html). The string length given the p256 curve order [page 91 in this NIST document](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf) gives the result `32` (Calculation on [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ceil(log2(115792089210356248762697446949407573529996955224135760342+422259061068512044369)%2F8)) ).